# Kafka-Zookeeper Authentication without SASL

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kerberos

I am trying to enable SASL_PLAINTEXT authentication between Kafka broker and client, while not requiring it between Kafka and Zookeeper. Currently I am using confluent offering of Kafka, with CDH Zookeeper. Is there a way to pass in a flag to disable SASL for Kafka <-> Zookeeper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the environment variable `ZOOKEEPER_SASL_ENABLED=false`. This is configured for Kafka broker